# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code:

```
public function getLists(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user()->id;
    $apikey = DB::table('apikey')->where('api_key', '=', $user);

    if($apikey){
    $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
    $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('lists',['fields' => 
        'lists.id,lists.name']);
    return Response::json($mailchimp_ping, 200);
    }
    else
    {        
        $errorResponse = [
            'message' => 'Lists not found!',
            'error' => '401'
        ];
        return Response::json( $errorResponse);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get mailchimp list based on logged in user id where i am doing wrong? is my where clause expects something else? 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: show your full error

Answer (score 2):

Use the `value()` method to execute the query and get the key. For example, if a column with key is called `apikey`:

```
$apikey = DB::table('apikey')->where('api_key', $user)->value('apikey');
```

Comment: Its saying (Call to a member function get() on null) My code is  $user = $request->user()->id;
            $apikey = DB::table('apikey')->where('api_key','=', $user)->value('api_key')->get();

Comment: @syed1234 remove `get()`, see the answer carefully

Comment: sorry my mistake i remove the get(); now its showing me Lists not found message

Comment: @syed1234 you shouldn't use `get()` because it will give you a collection and not string. The new error is not related to the question, so, you should create a new question and explain what exactly MailChimp package do you use, what exactly error do you have (full error message) etc.

Comment: I am using use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp; and its going to my else part showing lists not found even i have list against that apikey

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error  came up when changed this:

```
 Route::view('/report', '/main_pages/orders_parts/report')->name('guzorishi_order_1');
```

to

```
Route::get('/report/{order_id}', function ($order_id) {... })->name('guzorishi_order_1');
```

but forgot `Route::view` one
rename to `Route::get`